# Two csproj with different target frameworks

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a payment solution using an imported portable C# Library (a downloaded SDK). My current solution (which contains many projects all targeting .NET Framework 4) is a account management area which due to scale can not be updated to .NET Framework 4.5.

The new project I am importing is targeting .NET Framework 4.5, when I add this as a reference in my project I get a small warning triangle on the reference and therefore fails to build when running through BuildMonkey. Unfortunately we're unable to use .NET Framework 4 with this due to the methods used.

I wondered if there was any way around this, or any support for cross compatibility between the frameworks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use 4.0 library with 4.5 project. From the issue you mentioned it is possibly not finding the library, can you please check the path, remove and add the library again.

Comment: If I target the 4.5 project at 4, I get the following error: Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported.

Comment: And: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: Oh, just re-read your comments. It can find the project, and locally it builds fine.